# Grub Problems (but actually way more than just that)

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I have an old XP machine that I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on as a dual boot. Eventually I decided that I no longer needed Ubuntu (Wasn't compatible with Remote LogMeIn), and tried to remove Ubuntu using sub-par help topics on the internet.

Long story short, I ended up completely deleting the Linux partition (and what I assume was its swap space). I did not remove Grub, thinking that it would still work and allow me to boot into Windows until I could find an XP repair disk to restore the PC's default bootloader/ completely restore the PC to factory.

Here is my problem. Grub does not do anything but enter Grub rescue, and my PC will not boot into either the Windows Utility Partition OR a WinXP repair disk I burned when using the F12 boot menu.

I want to basically put my PC back to how it was before I installed Ubuntu, but I have dug myself into a hole.

I am really stumped...

Comment: Do you have an XP CD?

Comment: I do not have any of the repair/install disks the PC came with, but I have a disk I made using this: http://www.ehow.com/how_5875278_create-windows-xp-repair-cd.html

I'm not sure it actually works yet, seeing as I can't boot into anything using F12.

Comment: You can't even boot from CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the 2nd option on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

1. Boot with Ubuntu live CD/USB (mean installation media)
2. Install boot-repair with the instructions on this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
3. Open boot repair program but do not use recommended repair.
4. Click Advanced options and check Fix MBR, uncheck Reinstall Grub.
5. Apply it.

This should fix your Windows MBR (Main Boot Record)

Comment: Before I read this comment I started to install 12.04 from USB. Will these instructions still work with it installed rather than just being run from the USB?

Comment: Install it. No problem. After that open newly installed Ubuntu, install boot-repair and fix MBR with installed Ubuntu. When you restart the computer, new MBR will directly get in to the windows. After that, format the Ubuntu partition you installed with windows disk utility or appropriate program.

Comment: Appreciate it. You are wellcome.